How to initialize FileImage
I am using Flutter on desktop Windows.
I want to open an image file and load it into an image widget.
I get the error saying that FileImage must be initialized.
Could you please help.
Here is my code:
class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late FileImage? file;

  openFile () {
    setState(() async {
      file = await openFile();
    });
  }

  getFilePath(){
    return file.toString();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    Widget myfilepath = Text('Image File Path: '+getFilePath());
    Widget myimage = Image.file(File(getFilePath()));
    Widget openButton = SizedBox(width: 1000,height: 30,child: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Expanded(child: TextButton(onPressed: openFile, child: const Text('Open File'))),
      ],
    ),
    );

    return Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,title: Text(widget.title),),
      body: Center(child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,children: <Widget>[
            myfilepath,
            openButton,
            myimage
          ],
        ),
      ),

    );
  }
}


What's the exact (copy/paste) error message and stack trace you get?

Nuget.exe not found, trying to download or use cached version.
LateInitializationError: Field 'file' has not be initialized.

You called Function openFile() inside setState() which is creating a recursive loop,
modify your code to this and call the openFile() when button clicked
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';

Future<void> openFile() async {
  var result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(type: FileType.image);
  if (result != null) {
    setState(() {
      file = File(result.files.single.path!); 
    });
  }
}


I added the code and I change file declaration to: late File? file; The code does not solve the problem. I get the same error: Nuget.exe not found, trying to download or use cached version. LateInitializationError: Field 'file' has not be initialized.
